# How can I promote Linux or ubuntu to my clients who are not very computer savy?

Tags: promotion

I am a computer techncian with a variety of clients, most of whom are not computer savey and are always looking for the easy solutions, but have a lot of problems with other oprating systems. When I talk to them about ubuntu they pull a funny face and say it is too much hard work. What do I say to them?

Comment: Yes, it is hard work if your clients have some software that they are using in Windows, for example and they need to know if there is an alternative software in Ubuntu or if they can install the software that they are already using in Ubuntu with Wine. They also need to know if they can count on your support to help them make the transition to Ubuntu, so it's hard work for you too.

Comment: Close voters: I notice that this question has been close voted for being "opinion based". My first comment is derived from a Linux Action Show video on this topic so even if it is "opinion based" it is based on the opinions of professionals whose job it is to help clients to switch to Linux. So it's not necessarily opinion based in a negative way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say what I am saying to my friends(windows users): Yes because It is new to you. You addicted to a none standard OS which prefer ease of use to safety. Ubuntu is a new world. With its graphical environment you will have same thing (very easy) but still very secure and stable. The hard part of Ubuntu is its command line. It is learn able and almost same thing as any other POSIX OS like mac and uinx and it will make you very powerful. I suggest you the ultimate power, security and stability. And more important it is all FREE!!!

Comment: They do like the free part. The just want a computer that runs and that they dont have maintain. that everything is done for them by the OS

Comment: well this is all I am saying. Graphical environment is very easy to use. Most user just run OS, playing a video or mp3, searching net and reading emails. All these task in Ubuntu are as easy as any other OS plus we have posix stability for free. like my brother. he is do not know any thing from computer. he doing all these things in my laptop with xubuntu in it. Now somehow he hate windows because he discovered ubuntu stability and do not want to lose it.

Comment: Windows is quite stable these days, and Ubuntu crashes now and then. Both Windows and Linux are stable. It's the apps you use that cause the (system) crashes. So depending on what you're going to do Ubuntu can crash as well. (Disclaimer: I am an Ubuntu fan and use it daily.) And how is Windows "none standard"? It's still the nr.1 OS - what is not standard about that?

Comment: totally disagree. Where I live windows viruses are every where. 99% of them transferring via usb memory stick. many of them pass the Anti viruses programs.  Poeple install a windows and after 3 months they reinstall windows because old one became so slow

Answer (score 0):

Is this about you, or about them? What is easy for you, and what is easy for them? If money is no objection, I would advice a Mac.

Many people want or need MS Office or Photoshop. If so, bad luck! Using Wine to get that working is a nightmare. I've tried it, and it doesn't work. After a while some problem will emerge, and it will be ugly. Virtualbox for these things is no option either, even a windowless VM will be confusing, with different GUIs. And it will result in the question - if Linux can't do this, why would I want it?

If they only browse the net, use Gmail or Hotmail or other online stuff, maybe Thunderbird, then you might get lucky. If they only use simple Excel sheets, without macros, and Word documents where layout it not important, then LibreOffice might be an alternative.

I see Ubuntu as a better alternative for Chrome OS for "normal" people. I use it as work desktop and may switch to it from my Mac in the future, although to be honest there are just too many apps that I can't do without.

If security and money are issues, then Ubuntu is a good choice. It runs on old hardware, it's easy to update and maintain if you stick to a default setup.

I can understand what you want, but be honest and think what is best for your clients. And if Windows fails often, doesn't that mean more money for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I find is the like you said the incompatibilty with some software. I am able to convince them with the fact that it is free.  Sometimes free is  not enough especially for business who know only windows and macs are way more expensive that other computers

Answer (score 0):

You can say that there is a possibility to install `Windows` software using `Wine` and maybe show them a computer with working `Windows software`. I also strongly recommend using `MATE`. And I presume you are installing software for them, so tell them about `Windows` software available as `Linux` versions. Also, you can point out that almost everything in `Linux` is free, show them how does `apt` work and how easy is to install software using `apt-get` or `aptitude`. Also, there is a plenty of software available as equivalents but for free.

Comment: Wine means using a Windows GUI for those programs. It's confusing, two different GUIs for people who don't really understand what's happening. And in my experience Wine always results in software problems.